# What is junit-bom and junit platform for, and should I include them in gradle dependencies?

Tags: java, gradle, junit, junit5, junit-jupiter

I'm reading [Junit 5 User Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/index.html#overview-getting-started-example-projects). It leads me to a [JUnit 5 Jupiter Gradle Sample](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/tree/c15fe17ee4cb5c7d601767dd4964f05711b6ada0/junit5-jupiter-starter-gradle), which is a simplest example of using Junit 5 with Gradle. In `build.gradle` file, there are 2 dependencies, `junit-jupiter` and `junit-bom`. And in `test` task, it also calls `useJUnitPlatform()` function.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation(platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.1'))
    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter')
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}
```

According to my knowledge, the `junit-jupiter` is the aggregate artifact, which pulls the following 3 artifacts,

1. junit-jupiter-api (compile dependency)
2. junit-jupiter-engine (runtime dependency)
3. junit-jupiter-params (for parameterized tests)

So I guess `junit-jupiter` is already enough for running JUnit Jupiter in my project (correct me if I was wrong). **I want to know what is `junit-bom` and `JUnitPlatform` for here?** Can I simply get rid of them? Thanks everyone:)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `junit-bom` is JUnit's Bill Of Materials (BOM). When including this BOM, it will ensure to align and manage all JUnit 5 dependency versions for you. You can find more information about the BOM concept as part of [this article](https://reflectoring.io/maven-bom/).

That's why you don't have to specify a version when importing `junit-jupiter`:

```
// with the BOM, no version needed
testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter')

// when using no BOM, version info is needed
testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.1')
```

You'll see the benefit of the BOM in case you import multiple dependencies from the same project. When just using one dependency, it might seem redundant:

```
// only define the version at a central place, that's nice
testImplementation(platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.1'))
testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter')
testImplementation('org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine') // when you want to also run JUnit 3 + 4 tests
```

The `useJUnitPlatform()` instructs the Gradle test task to use the JUnit Platform for executing your tests. That's required.

In your case, you have a minimal working setup to use JUnit 5 for a Gradle project. What you *could* do is to remove the `junit-bom` and add the version information yourself:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.1')
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}
```

But I would stick to the recommendation of the JUnit team and their sample projects on GitHub.

Comment: Great explanation of `junit-bom`! And for `JUnitPlatform()`, can I treat it as a test `Runner`? So that I don't have to explicitly write a `TestRunner` class to run the test?

Comment: with `JUnitPlatform()` you are referring to `useJUnitPlatform()`, right? By `Runner` you mean the JUnit 4 `Runner` API? Maybe the [relevant part](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#using_junit5) of the Gradle documentation can help here.

Comment: thanks for the references, I think I'm very close to the answer now. perhaps junit 5 just makes thing way too complicated than it should be...

Comment: According to the documentation: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-spring-boot: "...If your build relies on dependency management support from Spring Boot, you should not import the junit-bom in your build script since that will result in duplicate (and potentially conflicting) management of JUnit dependencies..." and therefore I wonder in general whether it is a good idea to use the BOM and whether Spring Boot is just a single case that causes problems ...